# Transformations for App.config Windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms, transformation

I want to have the different config for a build which creating after I press "Publish" in my Windows Form application, but I didn't see "Add Config Transforms" row. 
How can I create release config for my case?

Another question: is it possible to create release config for release build without publishing ? Just with compiling in a release.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the Visual Studio Extension and nuget package [Slow Cheetah](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) - this allows you to add transforms to app.config files. Both the Visual Studio extension and NuGet package are required.

Comment: It's worth noting that you only need the extension to modify the project to allow configs. Once that is done, any vanilla Visual Studio installation can build the project.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've installed SlowCheetah, but I still don't see "Add transformation" in my VS 2015. What's can be wrong ?